# GLB model does not render equally in different viewers

Tags: python

I have created cube model in Python with 6 different textures for each face.
While testing with different web viewers I've noticed that model shows properly ONLY with babylon.js whereas three.js and model-viewer are producing undesired opacity effect.

Is there anything I can change/fix in Blender in order to export model compatible with other viewers?

[link to model](https://www.unspins.io/wp-content/qb/glb1024/test.glb)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to only use one UV map per object since some viewers only take the first UV map into account. Therefor it might also make sense to pack your textures into one and use it with one UV map.

Comment: Any hints how to pack these textures into one and define this one texture for UV map?

Comment: If you Smart UV project the cube you will see in your UV map that 6 out of 9 tiles are occupied. Then you can use an image editing software like Photoshop or gimp to place your individual textures in the correct tile. An alternative is to bake the material into a new texture.

Comment: Created single texture using PIL by composing face textures accordingly to UV layout and exported glb. Problem still exist and does not relate with number of UV maps. But I found that it appears only if texture has set Alpha <1. Even Alpha=0.99 causes the same glitch

Comment: Can you share your blend file?

Comment: Sure, here's [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cNvJsPOLxMs2Ic7lYvYD3EVAlEOlb1Qn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The issue is related with transparency rendering in model-viewer and three.js web viewers. As soon there is Blend mode defined other that Opaque, these viewers are not rendering correctly object. As a workaround I've created cube which consists of 6 separate objects (planes) each with its own texture. Now I can't figure out how to define animation that mimics the whole cube instead of ainimated separate planes.